# When defining a CodePipeline via CDK, how to prevent it running 1st time automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am defining some CodePipelines in my CDK project, but am running into an annoying issue: Whenever the pipeline is created for the 1st time, it automatically starts to execute. This behavior persists even if I disable triggerOnPush for the source.

Anyone know how to disable this behavior?

I know there are some workarounds like adding a "manual approve" step or something, but this is not what I want. I just want to create the pipeline and leave it in a "never ran" state.

Comment: Can you explain the use-case?

Comment: I have some pipelines that do clean-up jobs / destroy some resources and I don't want them to run accidentally.

Comment: You're using the wrong tools. Would a plain CodeBuild project work?

Comment: I'm wondering about this same thing. We have a cross-account pipeline from dev to e2e to preprod to prod with manual approval. That's great for the day-to-day operations, but sometimes we need to deploy hotfixes directly to prod (e.g. a configuration change that doesn't affect any other env) and we do not have time to wait for the whole pipeline to finish. 

We're planning on creating a manually triggered hotfix-pipeline beside the main pipeline for this purpose and it would be great if it didn't trigger automatically on create.